# Append a list to polygon feature in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a multi-polygon shapefile where every polygon represents a biotope.
For every plant species that lives inside the biotope, I have an Excel file with the different species listed.

Both, the polygon and the species list have an Biotope-Nr. so that they can be connected.

The plan is to be able to read the species list whenever I use the Identify tool on the polygon in QGIS.

[image]

But I don't want to make a join between polygon and species list because I want the list to remain like it is. 'Dragging' the species list into the attribute table would result in a different kind of list which is difficult to read.

[image]

At the end I would like every polygon feature have a species list and whenever you click on it or select it with the 'Identify' tool, the list should appear. Is that possible?

---

The goal is: when clicking on a polygon feature, a propper list should 'appear' somewhere. One should be able to scroll through that list because it can be a long one. Example of such a list:

[image]

By clicking on another, nearby polygon feature, a different list should be visible (always the one with the matching Biotop-Nr.).

Comment: What would change about the list if you joined it?

Comment: As mentioned by @Erik: joining the list would not change it. If you don't feel comfortable joining them permanently, join them once, than save the Biotope layer and you have the values of the joined layer included as new attributes in the new layer. Than you can delete the join and your list remains unaltered.

Comment: If the layer could be ported to a geopackage: maybe format the list as a HTML file and put the files in a BLOB field with a corresponding widget to show the file on identify? It loses the ability to be dynamic though.

Comment: @Erik It is supposed to be a vertical list

Answer (score 1):

You want to format the list as an array field in your table. That way, it'll appear as a vertical list in the Identify window. Example from something I did recently using two publicly available data sources, looking at piracy events from the [ICC Piracy database](https://www.icc-ccs.org/piracy-reporting-centre/live-piracy-map) nearby [underwater sea cables](https://www.submarinecablemap.com/). Nearby cable names and distances are converted into a string and arrayed:

```
SELECT 
a.pk,a.geom,
array_agg('Cable: ' || b.slug || '; distance(m): ' || st_distance(st_transform(a.geom, 3857), st_transform(b.geom, 3857))) AS nearby_cables
FROM icc_piracy a
JOIN submarine_cable_map b ON st_intersects(st_transform(a.geom, 3857), st_buffer(st_transform(b.geom, 3857), 30000))
GROUP BY a.pk;
```

| pk | geom | nearby_cables |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 125 | 0101000020E61000005055555555B54940EEEEEEEEEEEE2B40 | {"Cable: seamewe-4; distance(m): 26371.62501407918","Cable: seacomtata-tgn-eurasia; distance(m): 23721.59184148823","Cable: imewe; distance(m): 6848.222517281094","Cable: europe-india-gateway-eig; distance(m): 9852.220641087546"} |

How it looks in QGIS:

[image]

That's using PostGIS to generate the array field.

Comment: Good approach. The list that should appear when clicking on a polygon feature, should be vertical, like a normal list.

Comment: It does appear as a vertical list.

Answer (score 1):

Go into your Project Properties under the File menu, and pick the Relations tab at the bottom. Select Add Relation to bring up the configuration dialog to set up the link. Give the relation link a name, then set your child and parent features.
-Relation 1:N.
-Join 1:1
-Using aggregate functions (qgis) and array list.
-Sql query.

Comment: I tried to make a Relation but then how do I proceed? I think aggregate is a good way. The goal is that, by clicking on one polygon feature, the list with all the species with a certain biotope-number should appear